# Changing dimensions of woocommerce category image only not product image

Tags: wordpress, css, woocommerce, categories

I'm using a shortcode on my homepage http://patriotprepared.com/ to display specific categories in 3 columns with a total of 6 categories.  They display just fine without any customizing of CSS.  However, I want to reduce the size of the category images (not product images) so that the category images will be reduced by about 50%.  I can't seem to target a specific tag without affecting the product image sizes as well.

Surely, someone else has encountered this issue, but I have been searching for about 45 minutes with no luck. Is there a way to attach a class to a shortcode to target just that occurrence of the shortcode?  Be nice, I haven't been working with Woocommerce or Wordpress that long.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that asking general questions like this is discouraged, questions should only be posted after you have researched your issue and should include your attempts so far along with the relevant code. This will also help your chance of getting help. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I decided the easiest thing to do was to change the shortcode to 6 columns with 6 categories. Apparently, WooCommerce changes the image sizes based on number of columns.